# Mobile only image display issue

Tags: html, css, image, mobile

I'm trying to have an image appear only when viewed on a mobile device. I got it to not display in my desktop css, but now it won't show even when I write it in my media query. Any ideas why it won't appear?

HTML:

```
 <div class="panel specs">
  <div class="content">

  <a name="jumpspecs"></a>

<h2> Specifications </h2>
<img src="images/vespaspecs.png" alt="vespaspecs">

<div class="mobileshow">
<img src="images/mobilevespa.png" alt="mobilevespa">
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .specs .mobileshow {
   display: none;
 }

/* MOBILE */

@media (max-width: 667px) {

.specs .mobileshow {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSS works fine, although you're missing a closing bracket at the end:

```
@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .specs .mobileshow {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYZEbp

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the css properties for your image to "visibility" instead of display. You would be able to toggle between "visibility: hidden" and "visibility: visible" between media sizes

Comment: Keep in mind that elements with ```visibility: hidden``` will still take up space in the painted layout, whereas ```display: none``` will collapse the surrounding elements as if the DOM element isn't even there.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something else other than your code that's missing.

I copied your code and it works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/b9g363od/

```
.specs .mobileshow {
   display: none;
 }

@media (max-width: 667px) {
  .specs .mobileshow {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Have you tried hard resetting your browser?
https://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a bracket in your media query

```
/* MOBILE */

@media (max-width: 667px) {

.specs .mobileshow {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

}
```

Update your CSS and do a hard refresh by pressing ctrl + f5